# Using xlswrite to save data from an array? Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, xls

I have created a GUI with matlab and at the end of it the user has the option to save the data and it saves to an excel file which they chose.
Theres two seperate sets of data saved and written to the excel file. The first one is one numerical value `IntensityValue2` such as `4592.25` and `OtherAUC2` which is an array of different numerical values such as `[]    [5025.8]    [5012.3]    [4963.45]`
Here is the code I am using:

```
% --- Executes on button press in Save.
function Save_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Save (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
IntensityValue = getappdata(0,'IV');

[FileName,PathName]= uigetfile('*.xlsx*','File to save to');
intensityfile = fullfile(PathName,FileName);
filename = intensityfile;
mypeak = {'Peak(nm)'};
xlswrite(filename,mypeak,'Sheet1','A1');
myintensity = {'Intensity'};
  xlswrite(filename,myintensity,'Sheet1','B1');
IntensityValue2 = str2num(IntensityValue);
  xlswrite(filename,IntensityValue2,'Sheet1','B2');
OtherAUC = getappdata(0,'AUC')
numfiles = getappdata(0,'files');
for a = 2:numfiles
    OtherAUC2{a} = OtherAUC{a}
end
xlswrite(filename,OtherAUC2,'Sheet1','B3');
```

At the moment the excel file looks something like this:

```
Peak(nm)  Intensity
          4592.25  
                    5025.8  5012.3  4963.45
```

Whereas I would like it to look like this:

```
Peak(nm)   Intensity  
           4592.25
           5025.8  
           5012.3  
           4963.45
```

Can anybody help me achieve this? I realise the first cell is empty in `OtherAUC2`but I thought the foor loop would have meant the first cell is not written to the excel file. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For the orientation, transposing `OtherAUC2` should fix the issue (`OtherAUC2.'`). Specifying the exact cell range should also work, but isn't as flexible. For the blank cell, what is the result of `whos` for `OtherAUC` and `OtherAUC2`?

Comment: @excaza thank you I will try transposing `OtherAUC2`. The results for whos for OtherAUC is `Name: OtherAUC Size: 1x4 Bytes:368 Class:cell Attributes:` and for OtherAUC2 is `Name: OtherAUC2 Size: 1x4 Bytes:368 Class:cell Attributes:`

Comment: Oh, duh, I missed it the first time I looked. Use `OtherAUC2{a-1} = OtherAUC{a}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to recap:

When `xlswrite` writes data to an excel file, the layout will be the same as the layout in MATLAB. So if you have a 1x4 array it will write one row and if you have a 4x1 array it will write one column. To reshape this array you can use MATLAB's [`transpose`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) function, which is often abbreviated to `.'` (complex conjugate) or `'` (transpose). All three will be equivalent in this case.

So for your application you have two methods:

```
OtherAUC2 = OtherAUC2.';
xlswrite(filename,OtherAUC2,'Sheet1','B3');

% or

xlswrite(filename,OtherAUC2.','Sheet1','B3');
```

Both methods should give you the result you're looking for.

For the second part, your `for` loop just needs to be tweaked. You were correct to start the loop index at 2 in order to skip the blank value, but you forgot to account for index shift in the new array.

All you need to do is subtract one from your `OtherAUC2` index:

```
for a = 2:numfiles
    OtherAUC2{a-1} = OtherAUC{a}
end
```

Alternatively, you can delete empty cells without a loop:

`OtherAUC = OtherAUC(~cellfun(@isempty, OtherAUC));`

[`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) applies the specified function to each cell in a cell array, which eliminates the need for loops in many situations. Here what it's doing is going through each cell and seeing if it's empty. It then redefines `OtherAUC` to be every cell that is not empty. This is an example of [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) (`~cellfun(@isempty, OtherAUC)` returns a 1x4 logical array, where `FALSE` is an empty cell).

You can accomplish the same thing with a numerical array:

```
test = [NaN,2,3,4];
test(isnan(test)) = [];

% or

test = [0,2,3,4];
test(test==0) = [];
```

Just be careful with [floating point errors](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/41536-why-is-2-24-10-22-4-not-equal-to-0) when comparing non-integers and not using a tolerance.